# How to show Progressbar untill a process ends

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a problem when I' trying to show a progress bar until a external process ends which I started for the WPF window.

The code is like this:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Button1.IsEnabled = false;
    Button1.Content = "Please Wait";
    ProgressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;   

    if (a == 1 && b == 0) 
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"External Process Path 1");
        processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";

        try
        {
            Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        }
        catch (Win32Exception ex)
        {            
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Run As",
                MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
    }

    if (b == 1 && a == 0)
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"External Process Patch 2");
        processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";

        try
        {
            Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        }
        catch (Win32Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Run As",
                MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
    }

    Button2.IsEnabled = true;
    ProgressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; //This is what I want to toggle after process ends
}
```

I've tried Thread.Sleep(time) method and also for-loop but nothing seems to work.
I'm very new in WPF. So, please try to be a little brief.

Thanks,
D.K.

Comment: Use a `backgroundworker`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you know how long the external process lasts? if you don't you can try to set the IsIndeterminate property to true on your progress bar. this will show a continuous animation. When your process returns you can set it to false again in order to stop the animation.

also, in your code, i think you're not waiting for the process to finish. you could do this by using the code below.

```
Process p = Process.Start("IExplore");
p.WaitForExit();
```

please note that WaitForExit() blocks the current thread. as a result the app will stop responding. to keep the UI responsive you might like to start your process on a different thread like below.

```
private void onClick_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //disable button here
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        Process p = Process.Start("IExplore");
        p.WaitForExit();
        //enable button here. make sure to do this on the UI thread
        //since you're doing this in the code-behind you should have access
        //to the dispatcher
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)OnUpdateUI);
    });            
}
private void OnUpdateUI(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you are starting a process but not waiting for it to end, so the debugger when executes your:

```
Process.Star("Add Some Task");
```

, it jumps on to the next statement which is

```
button2.IsEnabled = true;
```

and so on. As a result your ProgressBar1 is not visible to you.

Please wait for the Process to end first. Write

```
Process.WaitForExit();
```

just after your statement

```
Process.Start("Your already started task");
```

Also you can create an Asynchronous thread to run in parallel.

Example:

```
Task taskA = new Task( () => Console.WriteLine("Hello from taskA."));
taskA.Start();        
taskA.Wait();
```

Also in your above code, you are only displaying ProgressBar but not updating its value with time. So as a result ProgressBar will be visible only with initial value.

For ProgressBar, do something like,

```
ProgressBar ProgressBar1 = new ProgressBar();
ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100;
ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0;
Task.Start();
if( Task.Status == "Running")
{
    ProgressBar1.Value = 50;
}
if( Task.Status == "completed")
{
    ProgressBar1.Value =100;
}
else 
{
    ProgressBar.Value=0;
    Task.Wait();
}
```

The code above mentioned may not be syntactically right. So do look for correct syntax.